Could a future Trump Attorney General dismiss the federal charges against Trump with prejudice?
The news accounts that I've seen have generally presumed that if Donald Trump wins the 2024 Presidential election and is sworn into office before either of his two federal trials begin, then his Attorney General will decline to pursue the federal charges that have been filed against him.
But I haven't seen anyone discuss what would happen after Trump's term ends in January 2029. Would it be possible for Trump's Attorney General to dismiss the charges against him with prejudice, thereby permanently ending the possibility of federal prosecution (for these particular crimes)? Or would the subsequent Attorney General be able to restart the prosecutions in 2029? Do any relevant statues of limitations come into play?

I don't know about the statute of limitations, which is why I'm not posting an answer, but only a court can dismiss charges with prejudice (that is, a judge).  Doing so means "this matter cannot be brought before this court again."  That is beyond the AG's authority.
